# Creating too much EventHandlers in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application

I want to make my JavaFX windows draggable. In order to do that I made a class that creates *MouseListener* for each scene to handle dragging:

```
public static void setDragListener(){
    root.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        xOffset = event.getSceneX();
        yOffset = event.getSceneY();
    });
    root.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
        stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
        stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
    });
}
```

So when I go to a new window I change my root for current scene and create new *MouseListeners*:

```
void goTo(String path, ActionEvent actionEvent){
    try {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(path));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        WindowDrag.setRoot(parent);
        WindowDrag.setDragListener();

        Stage window = (Stage)((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

What I am worried about is leaving previous *Listeners* as they are. Is it possible to run out of memory just by switching between scenes?

Comment: Your scene has a reference to the root, which has references to the listeners you defined. Once that scene is out of scope, there is no path to the listeners any more, and they can be garbage collected. So I don't see any problem here. The opposite is something you may need to think about; the listeners contain references to whatever object contains `xOffset` and `yOffset`, so as long as the listeners are in scope, the object containing those fields cannot be GC'd. It doesn't seem like this is a problem here though.

Comment: i have only one instance of `xOffset` and `yOffset` each. They are both static